# Jquery Validation: validate if the provided value is not <something>

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I want to validate a text field and its value may be anything except empty and Name.

if value of the text field is 'Name' then it must return some error. So is this possible through jquery validation?

If it is possible than please refer me with a simple example...

Comment: Can you provide some HTML, JQuery codes?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to do using this plugin... so what have you done so far to solve this problem yourself?  Questions like, _"gimme the codez"_, are frowned upon around here.  See http://sscce.org for how to write a proper question.  Otherwise, you could try reading the documentation...   http://jqueryvalidation.org  Hint: `.addMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addMethod` function to provide custom validation in the plugin:

[Reference:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredWithDefault", function(value, element, param) {
    var defaultValue = $(element).data("defaultValue");
    if($.trim(value).length > 0 && defaultValue !== value) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter required field."));
```

usage example

in html

```
<input type="text" name="element_name" id="element_name" value="Name" defaultValue="Name" />
```

in JavaScript

```
jQuery(FORM).validate({
    rules: {
        element_name: "requiredWithDefault"
    }, message: {
        element_name: "Custom message goes here"
    }
});
```